# What "make it through" means?

Tags: meaning, expressions

What "make it through" means? I heard it in a speech.

I googled it and found out "not die as a result of an illness or an accident, get better after an illness, recover, survive, respond". Is it right?

Comment: Details please. If you can provide more context, we can better answer the question. Why do you doubt the meaning found in the Google search?

Comment: I doubted the search because I thought the result was not enough. The context was a war story.

Comment: Which war story? *Please* provide the context.  That means either linking to the source or quoting a substantial amount of the speech before and around this expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a broader sense, it means to overcome a difficulty, to persevere, to go through a tough period, to undergo an unpleasant experience.

There is a song called ["Stone Cold"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDAd0S92Uko) where Demi Lovato sings

> Me and my heart, we'll make it through.

meaning she will find the strength to move on after breaking up with the person she was in love with.

Usually, it's *to make it through **sth*** implying a period of time, or describing a problem.

> [I'm just trying to *make it through **the day***.](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%27m%20just%20trying%20to%20make%20it%20through%20the%20day) *(informal)*
>
> You've *made it through **your labours*** and surely with the support of family and friends. *(a commencement address to graduates)*
>
> The Holy Spirit is our helper so we are able to *make it through **the storms of life***. *(a religious theme)*
>
> It is He that gives us the wisdom, insight, and fortitude to *make it through **the many obstacles*** we confront in this world. *(a religious theme)*